# mimimum difference of sum of subsequence

Tags: python, arrays

I have a sorted array. I want to divide it into two parts such that the difference of the sum of all the elements in that is minimum. For example, if I have an array `[1,4,9,16,25]` I will divide it into `S1=[1,9,16]` and `S2=[4,25]` such that I have the absolute minimum difference `(25+4)-(1+9+16)=3` which is the minimum possible.

```
        l,r,i=0,0,n-1
        while i>=0:
            if l<r:
                l+=arr[i]
            else:
                r+=arr[i]
            i-=1
```

This code is popping the Wrong Answer. How can I correct it?

Comment: You are iterating through the array in order. This way you can only produce results that split the array. Your preferred solution consists of partitions that are not in order, i.e. 4 ist in S2 but occurs before 9 which is in S1.

Comment: We need to have some more information :

* Should the two parts have the same length in case of even length or a difference of 1 in case of odd length ?

* Should that algorithm run in a particular time or space complexity ?

Comment: Also, you should provide us the algorithm you want to implement.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest and naive approach for this problem would be to use dynamic programming - since you can't predict the upcoming numbers in the next iterations, you can't decide at the moment of each iteration to which array you should add the current number. That's why your solution doesn't work, your decisions are being made eagerly. To decide to which of the arrays you should take the current number, you should be familiar with the whole original array - either do some pre-processing work or naively check all the available options (called brute force).

I'll try to demonstrate how to solve it with dynamic programming in pseudo code:

```
minDifferenceWrapper(arr) {
  return minDifference([], [], shallowCopy(arr))
}

minDifference(arr1, arr2, rest) {
  if rest.length == 0 -> return (arr1, arr2, calcDifference(arr1, arr2))
  
  nextNumber = rest.pop()
  option1 = minDifference(arr1.concat(nextNumber), arr2, shallowCopy(rest))
  option2 = minDifference(arr1, arr2.concat(nextNumber), shallowCopy(rest))

  // option1.diff is the returned value of calcDifference(arr1, arr2) 
  if option1.diff > option2.diff -> return option2 
  else return option1
}
```

**EDIT**
Implementation in Python:

```
import copy


def min_difference_wrapper(arr):
    return min_difference([], [], copy.copy(arr))


def min_difference(arr1, arr2, rest):
    if len(rest) == 0:
        return arr1, arr2, abs(sum(arr1) - sum(arr2))

    next_number = rest.pop()
    new_arr1 = copy.copy(arr1) + [next_number]
    option1 = min_difference(new_arr1, arr2, copy.copy(rest))
    new_arr2 = copy.copy(arr2) + [next_number]
    option2 = min_difference(arr1, new_arr2, copy.copy(rest))

    if option1[2] > option2[2]:
        return option2
    else:
        return option1


print(min_difference_wrapper([1, 4, 9, 16, 25]))
```

Comment: Note that this solution doesn't ensure minimal difference of sub-arrays length. You could have one sub-array with 3 elements and the other one with 1 element.

Comment: Is it expected? The question didn't state that the array lengths should be with minimal difference